# How I can show/fetch Excel data from date to date in datagridview in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, filter

I must write a program in C# .NET, that load and show data in Excel file in datagridview, then I want to use date to date(filter) to show excel file data according to choosing date.
I have 7 columns and 1800 rows in my Excel and I have DateTimePicker1 &  DateTimePicker2 to choose from_to(date) and button to show filter(date to date).
 I wrote a program that download and show excel file in datagridview but I cann't show the filter date.
**Can you help me please, How I can do a filter for my excel file data in C#.**

**here I need help please how I can show Date to Date excel data, I try with this code but it dose not work,**

```
    //======================Filter button ========================
    private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            DateTime startSchedule = startDate.Value.Date;
            DateTime endSchedule = endDate.Value.Date;


            string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * From[" + drop_down_sheet.SelectedValue + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
           /* foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(tb_path.Text); //?.....

            }*/
string filter = "Date > '" + startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND  Date < '" + endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
          DataRow[] filteredRows = dt.Select(filter);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
         "Important Note",
         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         MessageBoxIcon.Error,
         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't far wrong!  The easiest way to filter the results in the `DataTable` is by using the `Select` method which returns `DataRow[]`. This needs to be converted back to a `DataTable` to be used as the `DataSource`.

Something like this (after the `Fill`):

```
string filter = "YourDateColumn > '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND YourDateColumn < '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
DataRow[] filteredRows = dt.Select(filter);
dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Obviously you need to change YourDateColumn to whatever the name of the column is in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but where I have to put this code befor for loop or after it, should I change somethig in my code or not.

Comment: No, it replaces your entire `foreach` loop.  `DataSource` only gets set once!

Comment: Should I change something in this row,  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * ", con);//?......

Comment: Without knowing your spreadsheet it is hard to say, but normally it should be something on the lines of `"Select * FROM [Sheet1$]"` assuming the sheet is named Sheet1 - the default for English Excel

Comment: Look to my code now please after editing, I replace your code , is this right or not?

Comment: I cannot say without knowing what is in your spreadsheet, or what the drop_down_sheet has as selected value. Note in English you need to add $ to the Sheet name. Also you may need a space after `FROM`. Are you getting results now?

Comment: in my  spreadsheet, 7 columns,"Date ,projectname , personname, time….",and 1000 row. drop_down_sheet is compobox's name to choose which sheet I want, I get error that is " the source contains no data row"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202329/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-osama).